# Active Admin Custom Join Table for Filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, activeadmin, meta-search

I am using Active Admin with metasearch.  I have a habtm relationship but the join table is not the default one.  I have

```rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events, :join_table => 'events_staff'
end
```

```rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :staff, :class_name => 'Person', :join_table => 'events_staff'
end
```

When I use active admin, I wanted something like:

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Person do
  filter :events, :join_table => 'events_staff'
end
```

Renaming the models is not an option.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this question: [How do I do multiple has_and_belongs_to_many associations between the same two classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876312/how-do-i-do-multiple-has-and-belongs-to-many-associations-between-the-same-two-c) gave me a strategy to rename my relation in the Person model.  So now I have:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :staffed_events, :join_table => 'events_staff', :class_name => 'Event'
end
```

And my filter is filter :staffed_events